Kafka connector giving error when trying to connect oracle DB debezium
When I am trying to connect to the database, I am encountering an error. I believe it's  a DB-side error:
We have below from DB:

Execute access on TABLE
Read access to SCHEMA
SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE u=USER

Can someone please suggest what's wrong and what steps we need to take to mitigate this error:

Error :- trace: "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: An
exception occurred in the change event producer. This connector will
be stopped.\n\tat
io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler.setProducerThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:67)\n\tat
io.debezium.connector.oracle.logminer.LogMinerStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(LogMinerStreamingChangeEventSource.java:267)\n\tat
io.debezium.connector.oracle.logminer.LogMinerStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(LogMinerStreamingChangeEventSource.java:61)\n\tat
io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.streamEvents(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:280)\n\tat
io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.executeChangeEventSources(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:197)\n\tat
io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:140)\n\tat
.run(Unknown Source)\n\tat
java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat
java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:866)\nCaused by:
io.debezium.DebeziumException: Online REDO LOG files or archive log
files do not contain the offset scn 198567519.  Please perform a new
snapshot.\n\tat
io.debezium.connector.oracle.logminer.LogMinerStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(LogMinerStreamingChangeEventSource.java:165)\n\t...
10 more\n"
DBA team suggested us to perform snapshot
io.debezium.DebeziumException: Online REDO LOG files or archive log
files do not contain the offset scn 198567519.  Please perform a new
snapshot.\n\tat
io.debezium.connector.oracle.logminer.LogMinerStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(LogMinerStreamingChangeEventSource.java:165)\n\t...
10 more\n"


This log often indicates possible reason that is online redo log of Oracle is archived to archive logs. Therefore, you'll get the following message:

Online REDO LOG files or archive log files do not contain the offset scn

You'll be able to continue streaming datas when you recreate a new connector.
